# How to make a long equation small to fit in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations, formatting

I am trying to use one equation in my thesis but that equation is long enough to fit in LaTeX format, I found one image but don't know how to convert that into LaTeX format, it uses some different symbols.

[image]

How to write this in LaTeX and make it small.

What I have tried:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum_{i j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{n_{i j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)-\left[\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{i}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right) \sum_{j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{b_{j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)\right] /\left(\begin{array}{l}{n} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)}{\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{i}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)+\sum_{j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{b_{j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)-\left[\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{i}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right) \sum_{j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)\right] /\left(\begin{array}{l}{n} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)\right.}
\end{equation}
```

But it's appearing like this:

[image]

> **Edit:**

```
%File: formatting-instruction.tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{courier}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\pdfinfo{
/Title (Insert Your Title Here)
/Author (Put All Your Authors Here, Separated by Commas)}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  
 \begin{document}
% The file aaai.sty is the style file for AAAI Press 
% proceedings, working notes, and technical reports.
%
\title{Thesis}
\author{Anonymous Author 
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\begin{quote}
AAAI creates proceedings, working notes, and technical reports directly from electronic source furnished by the authors. To ensure that all papers in the publication have a uniform appearance, authors must adhere to the following instructions. 
\end{quote}
\end{abstract}

\section{Model}

In this section we describe the architecture of our model.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum_{i j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{n_{i j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)-\left[\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{i}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right) \sum_{j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{b_{j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)\right] /\left(\begin{array}{l}{n} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)}{\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{i}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)+\sum_{j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{b_{j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)-\left[\sum_{i}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{i}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right) \sum_{j}\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{j}} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)\right] /\left(\begin{array}{l}{n} \\ {2}\end{array}\right)\right.}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE which reproduce your problem. Code fragment is not very helpful for helping you ....

Comment: I already provided the code.

Comment: @AadityaUra no providing a fragment just makes it hard for people to help you, please provide a test document. In particular you are asking how to make the equation fit without giving any information about how wide your column is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please check

Comment: @Zarko Please check

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I change `\usepackage{times}` into `\usepackage{mathptmx}` in your code and also the equation into

```latex
\begin{equation}
\frac{
  \sum_{ij}\binom{n_{ij}}{2}-\bigl[\sum_{i}\binom{a_{i}}{2} \sum_{j}\binom{b_{j}}{2}\bigr]\big/\binom{n}{2}
}{
  \frac{1}{2}\bigl[\sum_{i}\binom{a_{i}}{2}+\sum_{j}\binom{b_{j}}{2}\bigr]-
  \bigl[\sum_{i}\binom{a_{i}}{2} \sum_{j}\binom{a_{j}}{2}\bigr]
  \big/\binom{n}{2}     
}
\end{equation}
```

I get (dummy text added for context)

[image]

The output is even better if I change `\usepackage{mathptmx}` into

```latex
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

[image]

If you want the description texts,

```latex
\begin{equation}
\overbrace{\mathit{ARI}}^{\hidewidth\substack{\text{Adjusted}\\\text{Index}}\hidewidth}=
\frac{
  \overbrace{\textstyle\sum_{ij}\binom{\vphantom{b}n_{ij}}{2}}^{\text{Index}}
  -
  \overbrace{\textstyle\bigl[\sum_{i}\binom{a_{i}}{2} \sum_{j}\binom{b_{j}}{2}\bigr]\big/\binom{n}{2}}%
    ^{\text{Expected Index}}
}{
  \underbrace{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\bigl[\sum_{i}\binom{a_{i}}{2}+\sum_{j}\binom{b_{j}}{2}\bigr]}%
    _{\text{Max Index}}
  -
  \underbrace{\textstyle\bigl[\sum_{i}\binom{a_{i}}{2} \sum_{j}\binom{a_{j}}{2}\bigr]\big/\binom{n}{2}}%
    _{\text{Expected Index}}
}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

1. With `\hidewidth`, the description above “ARI” takes no space; it is also split into two lines not to intrude the right-hand side.
2. `\textstyle` is necessary, because `\overbrace` and `\underbrace` force `\displaystyle`
3. The `\vphantom{b}` has been added to set “Index” at the same height as the other description.

Comment: I can't give more than one upvote :P

Comment: @AadityaUra I've just added a small change to the solution with the braces.

Comment: @AadityaUra There is also the mine :-)

Comment: @AadityaUra Well, for advice like “use `mathptmx` or NewTX we're here. For learning how to type mathematics, experience and desire to learn. I'd usually avoid those over/underbraces and explain the parts separately before stating the equation.